# Obtener un valor de un input con Jquery

Tags: jquery, random, entrada

tengo que hacer una pagina que piense un numero random y después con un input introducir ese numero, si no es el numero random que me diga si es mas pequeño o mas grande.

Bien, lo que me resulta un problema es que cuando introduzco un input no me dice si es mayor o menos, ojo! tiene que ser sin pulsar un submit ni nada que me diga si es mayor o no

```js
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function(sKey) {
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function(sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) {
      return false;
    }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },


  removeItem: function(sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) {
      return false;
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function(sKey) {
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: /* optional method: you can safely remove it! */ function() {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nIdx = 0; nIdx < aKeys.length; nIdx++) {
      aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]);
    }
    return aKeys;
  }
};

function numeroAleatorio(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
var random = numeroAleatorio(1, 100);
var valor;
if (docCookies.hasItem("comptador")) { //Existeix la cookie comptador?
  random = parseInt(docCookies.getItem("comptador")); //obté la cookie, però és una cadena, així que la pasa a enter
  docCookies.setItem("comptador", random, new Date(2020, 5, 12)); //Desem la cookie per a que quan es recarregue la pàgina, el navegador s'enrecorde del seu valor

} else {
  docCookies.setItem("comptador", random); //Desem la cookie per a que quan es recarregue la pàgina, el navegador s'enrecorde del seu valor
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="num" value="" size="20" /> Recarrega la pàgina per veure el valor del comptador. <br /><br />
<a href="" onclick="docCookies.removeItem('comptador')">Esborra la cookie</a>
```

Comment: podrías incluír tu código que has intentado hacer junto con el html por favor

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, debes agregar el código que estás usado o el que has intentado, también debes agregar los posibles errores que te haya arrojado, te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla, también deberías leer [ask] slaudos!

Comment: Si creo que lo entiendo bien, en ese tema es haciendo con el uso del evento "click"

Comment: Pero con el codigo ese Molix 97, en cuanto acabe de escribir m'he ejecutara el alert diciendo si es mayor o menor? Obviamente cuento con hacer las condiciones antes

Answer (score 0):

En el html tendrías que poner para poner el campo en el que meter el número:

```
<input type="number" id="loquequieras">
```

Y luego en lo de jquery en el head (entre etiquetas ) deberías poner como cuando usas un selector en CSS, sería algo así:

```
var x = $("#loquequieras").val();
```

El símbolo $ es para que lo haga con jquery y el # para que lo coja como ID.